# Specifying autofill (autocomplete) for iPhone Safari in HTML/JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, safari, autocomplete, jsx

The HTML attribute autocomplete="off" doesn't have an effect on iPhone Safari. In addition, iPhone Safari will look at the title, name, and placeholder fields to attempt to resolve the type of value that a field should autofill to.

As a result, an input written in JSX like this:

```
<input
placeholder="* Property Name"
autoComplete="off"
/>
```

Will always result in the field being autofilled to the user's full name - as if the autoComplete field (capital C in JSX, lowercase in HTML) were set to "name".

I have seen various threads with solutions that no longer work, such as `autoComplete="new-password"`.

One solution that I have found that does work is to replace the latin 'a' in 'name' with the cyrillic 'а', like so:

```
<input
placeholder="* Property Nаme"
autoComplete="off"
/>
```

As a result, the field will no longer autocomplete to the user's full actual name.

However, this seems like a hacky solution that could potentially cause a crash if the character set of a device or font only has ascii characters.

How are others solving this in 2023?